# Ansible inventory export to CSV file

Tags: csv, ansible, export

I am trying to get the inventory of my servers under Ansible from a static list to a CSV-like file where we have select list of fields, separated by commas. Something we can easily import into Excel for consolidated inventory, where we have our different instances of Ansible that are running. We have different instances as the different networks we have cannot talk to each other. Ultimately, we would like to produce a .XLSX file that we can mail automatically to management. But maybe I am dreaming at this point......

Comment: We are still in early development and we have an Ansible setup in a lab, where we will run those playbooks and scripts. Then, we will go on the real thing to grab the inventories.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Ansible API to run the `setup` module.

In the API [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html#python-api-2-0) you can see how to run a module, so the related part with `setup` module call may look like that:

```
play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = 'all',
        gather_facts = 'yes',
        tasks = [{"action":{"module":"setup"}}]
    )
```

And to parse your results, you'll use a callback to process returned data and save it in CSV:

```
import csv

class ResultCallback(CallbackBase):
    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
        host = result._host
        data = result._result
        # parse/process data
        # ....
        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            csv_writer.writerows(parsed_data)
```

Hope that helps little bit.

Comment: The second script is the Python script to run on the input file, right? I'm a complete newbie to Python. Is this script that can the output from, say , the JSON-formatted output ? I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: @jfmessier No, both examples are just parts of indicated [example](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html#python-api-2-0) from Ansible API documentation. Take the complete snippet from this link and try to change related parts as I mentioned.

Comment: Briefly, I tried to show how to adapt basic example to your case.